# Сброс данных при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: jquery

Делаю автоподрузку контента при поиске

`php` скрипт поиска выдаёт для ориентации ссылку вида

```
<a href="/actions/search.php?count=20&text=search"></a> //она скрыта
```

На самой странице поиска обработчик

```
var AJAX = (function(){
    var req = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();

    return {
        get : function(url, callback, context){
            req.open('GET', url);
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(req.readyState == 4){
                    callback.call(context || window, req);
                }
            };
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
});
```

проблема в том, что при вводе нового запроса на поиск и по нажатии на кнопку *Найти*, в поиске фигурируют старые данные, типа номер, откуда должен идти просмотр. как это всё сбросить и начать новый чисто новый поиск? в `jquery` не очень силён.

на всякий случай код отправки:

```
var content = $("#content"),
    loading = "load";
var btns = $('#search');

btns.click(function() {
    content.html('');
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/actions/search.php",
        data: { 'text': text },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $(".load").hide();
            content.append(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            content.append("<div class='load'>" + loading + "</div>");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Есть подключаемый js скрипт, отвечающий за скролл, но он роли не ирает